# Itunes Connect/Testflight disappear build after success processing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Im uploading a new version of my app and since yesterday after a success upload and Processing (got email with the success status) the build disappear from Version list in testflight.

Comment: Did you every figure this out? Seems like we have a similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471405/build-not-available-on-itunes-connect-for-internal-testing-through-circleci-fast